# VS Code different error with import or without import

Tags: javascript, html

I don't understand and don't know how to solve error below.

- When I DON'T USE (import fs from "fs";)
- I get this error (Uncaught ReferenceError ReferenceError: require is not defined)
- When I USE (import fs from "fs";)
- I get (Uncaught SyntaxError SyntaxError: Identifier 'fs' has already been declared)

I am trying to read fail_drive.log into an array with content below:

1
3
4
7
8

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
body {
  background-color: lightblue;
}

.main {
  text-align: center;
}

.div1 {
  width: 20%;
  height: auto;

}

.row {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  column-gap: 2px;
}

.slot {
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 20%;
  height: 70px;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}
.failed::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  background-color: red;
  width: 40px;
  height: 40px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation: 1s blink ease infinite;
}
@keyframes blink {
  from,
  to {
    opacity: 0;
  }
  50% {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
  <h1 class="main">Phy Link Test</h2>


<div class="div1" >
  <h2>Front Chassis</h2>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="slot" id='slot-17'><img src="Downloads\cut_images_archive_ZMcuieGmjsPU\cut_images_4sW7CkxiWzf1Ya/23.png" alt="17"></div>
      <div class="slot" id='slot-14'><img src="\Downloads\cut_images_archive_ZMcuieGmjsPU\cut_images_4sW7CkxiWzf1Ya/20.png" alt="14"></div>
      <div class="slot" id='slot-5'><img src="\Downloads\cut_images_archive_ZMcuieGmjsPU\cut_images_4sW7CkxiWzf1Ya/5.png" alt="5"></div>
      <div class="slot" id='slot-2'><img src="\Downloads\cut_images_archive_ZMcuieGmjsPU\cut_images_4sW7CkxiWzf1Ya/2.png" alt="2"></div>
      <div>top slot</div>
    </div>
    
</div>
<script type="module">

import fs from "fs";

  
const fs = require('fs');
const fileContent = fs.readFileSync('C:\Users\john_ma\Downloads\cut_images_archive_ZMcuieGmjsPU\cut_images_4sW7CkxiWzf1Ya\fail_drive.log', 'utf8');
const lines = fileContent.split('\n');
console.log(lines);
  
  
  function toggleFailed(slotId) {
    const slot = document.getElementById('slot-' + slotId);
    slot.classList.toggle('failed');
  }
  
  for (const slotId of slotIds) {
    const slot = document.getElementById('slot-' + slotId);
    slot.addEventListener('click', () => toggleFailed(slotId));
  }
  </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why are you trying to import `fs` twice using different import methods? In your first scenario, `require` does not exist. In the second, since `import` is a valid statement and it declares a variable called `fs`, trying to declare another variable called `fs` tells you it already exists. It never gets to the `require` statement. Also this is front-end JavaScript and `fs` is a node library. Front-end JavaScript cannot read files directly off the system (for obvious security-related reasons), so you won't be able to do it like that. Use an API or expose the file via a URL.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot import/require `node:fs` from an average browser

To be able to use `fs` within a browser you need a browser with node support, like Electron or NWJS

As you're a newbie I recommend `nwjs` as there you can just open a folder with `index.html` with `nw.exe` and it'll work

Get a latest SDK (it has devtools) from https://nwjs.io/ , unzip it and drag your folder onto nw.exe

Comment: If I move my text file to online i.e. http://192.168.1.1/test.txt, what method can I use? I have search all day and nothing seem to work from XMHttpRequest, fetch.

Comment: You generally can't edit files from web, no matter where they are. The one who edits them is a server. Search for a simple CRUD server on node to get started (tl;dr it writes the file on HTTP POST and reads it on HTTP GET)

Comment: I don't want to write, I just need to read but don't want to use input button.

Comment: Then you need to open your html aslo on web (`92.168.1.1/index.html` or whatever). `fetch('test.txt')` should work.

Comment: `fetch('test.txt').then(response=>response.text()).then(text=>console.log(text))`